# Selenium invalid session Exception when opening multiple browsers

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

Im currently trying to write a script that gets some prices off a website and then i want to integrate it into a csv file. now when running it with one item, it works fine. When i try to open the browser again though, i get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains2\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains2\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/timjo/Desktop/BOTSCRIPT/Test.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver.get('https://buff.163.com/market/goods?goods_id=40086&from=market#tab=selling')
  File "C:\Users\timjo\Desktop\BOTSCRIPT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\timjo\Desktop\BOTSCRIPT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\timjo\Desktop\BOTSCRIPT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
```

I googled and found out that it needs to be compatible with the geckodriver, but the thing is, it works fine if i open the browser only once, which seems senseless to me. My script looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import csv
import time
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://buff.163.com/market/goods?goods_id=39968&from=market#tab=selling')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/div[1]/strong')
Price_C9_Col14 = element.text
driver.close()
time.sleep(10)

driver.get('https://buff.163.com/market/goods?goods_id=40086&from=market#tab=selling')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/div[1]/strong')
Price_Epsilon_Col14 = element.text
driver.close()


driver.get('https://buff.163.com/market/goods?goods_id=40151&from=market#tab=selling')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/div[1]/strong')
Price_F3_MLG16 = element.text
driver.close()


driver.get('https://buff.163.com/market/goods?goods_id=40106&from=market#tab=selling')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/div[1]/strong')
Price_Faze_MLG16 = element.text
driver.close()
print(Price_C9_Col14, Price_F3_MLG16, Price_Epsilon_Col14, Price_Faze_MLG16)
```

The end goal would be to run it in headless mode, but for now i try it with normal mode, to figure out what the problem might be. i also checked previous answers, but they were pretty old, therefore the compatible versions did not match the versions which we have today. Im using Python 3.9.0, idk about firefox and Selenium version, since i dont know where to check. Any tips / suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured out, that the driver.get function only changes the url and doesnt open another window, therefore i dont need the driver.close function and it works fine. i also added a time.sleep() in order to have the browser to access the site first, since it did always fetch the same price before